# Angular 6 wait method with subscribe inside

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, asynchronous

I have to call a service for several times, by forEach, a method that has subscribe (http call) inside and I have to wait each time for the end of previous call.
This is the code:

```
itemDefaultConfiguration.command = (onclick) => {
   this.createConfiguration(configuration.components);
   //wait the end of createConfiguration method that has subscribe (http call) inside
   this.initializeAllComponents(configuration.components)
};

initializeAllComponents(components: Agent[]) {
    components.forEach(agent => {
      this.componentService.setAgent(agent);
      this.componentService.clearAnyOneOfIndex();
      // wait the end of setAgent method that has subscribe(http call) inside
    })
}
```

inside componentService:

```
setAgent(agent: Agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
        this.selectComponent(agent.name, undefined, "/", "/", environment.maxLevelJsonSchema);
    }
```

and selectComponent has the subscribe.

```
selectComponent(agentName: string, propName: string, schemaPath: string, dataPath: string, deepLevel: number) {
        this.getComponentSchema(this.agentName, schemaPath, deepLevel)
            .subscribe((responseSchema) => {
                this.getDataFailure(propName, dataPath, responseSchema); 
            });
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You need to put some effort in instead of asking us to do it for you. At first glance you should probably rethink the strategy.

Comment: I tried with async/await but no change, I thought there is a way by RxJS

Comment: @please show `selectComponent` method

Comment: uodate with the subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), like:

```
initializeAllComponents(components: Agent[]) {
    components.forEach(async agent => {
      await this.componentService.setAgent(agent).catch(console.log);
      this.componentService.clearAnyOneOfIndex();
      // wait the end of setAgent method that has subscribe(http call) inside
    })
}
```

Comment: it doesn't wait the end of call

Comment: It means that setAgent returns data before!

Comment: Yes, setAgent call another method that have the subscribe

Comment: Try to make setAgent return the subscription itself in setAgent, and here use await setAgent().toPromise()

Comment: forEach doesnt wait, you need to use normal for loop, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax:

```
initializeAllComponents(components: Agent[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        const agent = components[i];
        await this.componentService.setAgent(agent).catch(console.log);
        this.componentService.clearAnyOneOfIndex();
    }
}
```

Be careful with `async/await`, because you need to use native `for` loop in order to wait previous call - `forEach`, `reduce` and similar methods just fires off multiple asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

If it is `Observable`, try to use `switchMap` operator:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

initializeAllComponents(components: Agent[]) {
    components.forEach(agent => {
      this.componentService.setAgent(agent).pipe(
           switchMap(res => {
               if (res) { return this.userService.get(user.uid); }

               return of(null);
           }));
      );
      this.componentService.clearAnyOneOfIndex();          
    })
}
```

If it is not `Observable`, then use `async/await` operators:

```
async initializeAllComponents(components: Agent[]) {
    components.forEach(agent => {
      let result = await this.componentService.setAgent(agent);
      this.componentService.clearAnyOneOfIndex();
      // wait the end of setAgent method that has subscribe(http call) inside
    })
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not observable

Comment: I updated the first post, setAgent call another method that has the subscribe inside